# Concat/union 3 Array together in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

i have a question how to concat or union 3 arrays in one line of the code?
I've got Visual Studio 2015 and it looks like

```
int[] array1 = {1 ,2 ,3 ,-5 ,2 ,0 };
int[] array2 = {1 ,2 ,3 ,-1 ,5 ,0 };
int[] array3 = {1 ,2 ,3 ,-6 ,2 ,9 };
```

and i wanna on button click to have like:

```
Console.WriteLine(array1.Union(array2.Union(array3)).Where((x) => x >=0).Count)
```

Dunno rly how to Union 3 array in single line

Comment: union and concatenation are not the same thing. What do you want your results to look like?

Comment: Well you just did it, what is there "not to know" ?

Comment: it's not work dunno why. I wanna to show all unique positive values from this 3 arrays and i wanna to have this in single line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that after the `Where` clause the `Count` is a function and not a property.

In addition a neater way will be to chain the `Union` instead. Also You can place the predicate in the `Count` instead:

```
Console.WriteLine(array1.Union(array2).Union(array3).Count(x => x >= 0));
```

---

To print only positive values of all arrays use [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array1.Union(array2).Union(array3).Where(x => x >= 0)));
//Prints: 1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 9
```

Comment: @DamianRożkowicz - see link added

Comment: yeah it's work thanks for help my comment didnt land here

Answer (score 1):

For a Union you just need

```
array1.Union(array2).Union(array3)
```

and then you can write and/or count the resulting IEnumerable. A Union disregards duplicates: if you want to preserve all the values from all 3 arrays (and continuing arrays instead of some list/collection type) you could do:

```
var concatenated = new int[array1.Length + array2.Length + array3.Length];
array1.CopyTo(concatenated, 0);
array2.CopyTo(concatenated, array1.Length);
array3.CopyTo(concatenated, array1.Length + array2.Length);
```

Comment: Fine if you have a a small known set of arrays, impractical if you have a larger or an unknown number of arrays to join. Use SelectMany.

Answer (score 0):

The following will concatenate the arrays by calling Concat.

Then remove the replicated numbers by calling Distinct.

Lastly filter out the numbers by calling Where with the predicate greater or equal to zero.

```
        var arr1 = new[] {1, 2, 3, -5, 2, 0};
        var arr2 = new[] {1, 2, 3, -1, 5, 0};
        var arr3 = new[] {1, 2, 3, -6, 2, 9};
        var result = arr1
            .Concat(arr2)
            .Concat(arr3)
            .Distinct()
            .Where(i => i >= 0)
            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in one line of code.
Use linq SelectMany to flatten arrays or lists.

```
// Set up array of arrays sample.
var a1 = new string[] { "z","x","d" };
var a2 = new string[] { "a","e","i" };
var a3 = new string[] { "q","m","w" };
var arrays = new string[][] { a1, a2, a3 };

var r = arrays.SelectMany(s => s);
```

Answer (score -1):

Generic concatenation of multiple arrays.

```
    //
    //
    ///<summary>Create a new array as concatenation of all given arrays.</summary>
    public static T[] Concatenate<T>( params T[][] args ) {
        if ( null == args ) return null;
        // Get argument lengths
        var count = args.Length;
        if ( 0 == count ) return null;
        var lengths = new int[ count ];
        // Compute all and total lengths
        var total = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
            lengths[ i ] = null == args[ i ] ? 0 : args[ i ].Length;
            total += lengths[ i ];
        }
        if ( 1 > total ) return null;
        // Create target array
        T[] a = new T[ total ];
        // Copy all together
        total = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
            if ( null != args[ i ] ) {
                args[ i ].CopyTo( a, total );
            }
            total += lengths[ i ];
        }
        return a;
    }
```